# Using Internet explorer to run React JS apps

Tags: reactjs, package.json

i'm a beginner in React and trying to run a few apps using Internet explorer and got struck with the below error. I have understood that package.json has a development section which describes something about the browser compatability. Can anyone help me understand why there is a limitation to run React apps especially using Internet explorer.

How to make the APP run on any browser? What is the significance of the below development section

```
"development": [
      "ie 11",
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
```

[image: Internet explorer description]

Above is the section included by default in the package.json (i have manually placed the ie 11).

Answer (score 1):

According to the RN [documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/supported-browsers-features/#supported-browsers):

> By default, the generated project supports all modern browsers. Support for Internet Explorer 9, 10, and 11 requires polyfills.

> Note that this does not include polyfills automatically for you. You will still need to polyfill language features as needed based on the browsers you are supporting.

So to support the `IE Browser` you need to add some polyfills based on the version of the `IE` which you want. first, you need to install the `react-app-polyfill`:

```
npm install react-app-polyfill
// or
yarn add react-app-polyfill
```

Now, import the polyfill the **first line in src/index.js**

##### Internet Explorer 9

```
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie9';
```

##### Internet Explorer 11

```
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';
```

More on `react-app-polyfill` [documentation](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/main/packages/react-app-polyfill/README.md#react-app-polyfill).